# How can i extract a number between two elements? (webscraping)

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm starting at webscraping and i want to extract the number between the `strong` elements.

I'm using python 3.8 and beautifulsoup

```
<li class="price-current">
    <span class="price-current-label">
    </span>$<strong>409</strong><sup>.99</sup> <a class="price-current-num" href="https://www.newegg.com/gigabyte-radeon-rx-5700-xt-gv-r57xtgaming-oc-8gd/p/N82E16814932208?Item=N82E16814932208&amp;buyingoptions=New">(5 Offers)</a>
    <span class="price-current-range">
        <abbr title="to">–</abbr>
    </span>
</li>
```

Comment: What does your code look like? What are "strong" elements, what is "the number" between them? Please look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number between `<strong>...</strong>`, you can use this example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<li class="price-current">
    <span class="price-current-label">
    </span>$<strong>409</strong><sup>.99</sup> <a class="price-current-num" href="https://www.newegg.com/gigabyte-radeon-rx-5700-xt-gv-r57xtgaming-oc-8gd/p/N82E16814932208?Item=N82E16814932208&amp;buyingoptions=New">(5 Offers)</a>
    <span class="price-current-range">
        <abbr title="to">–</abbr>
    </span>
</li>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print( soup.select_one('.price-current strong').text )
```

Prints:

```
409
```

---

To get the whole price (with price including the `.`), you can use `re` module:

```
import re

price = re.search(r'\$\d+.?\d*', soup.select_one('.price-current').text)
if price:
    print(price.group())
```

Prints:

```
$409.99
```